# Cannot play audio in Xcode project

Tags: ios, audio

This code works in a test app, but not in the app in which I want the audio to play.

```
-(void) playTutorialAudio
{
    _theAudioFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Welcome"  ofType:@"mp3"];

    NSLog(@"playTutorialAudio _theAudioFile %@",_theAudioFile);

    NSURL *playTutorialURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:_theAudioFile ];
    _audioPlayAlert =  [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:playTutorialURL error:NULL];
    [_audioPlayAlert setDelegate:self];
    [_audioPlayAlert prepareToPlay];
    _audioPlayAlert.volume = 1.0;
    [_audioPlayAlert play];
}
```

The code works with other audio files.

Comment: Why don't you use the error parameter of `[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL...]` ??

Comment: Look at my implementation for the `[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ting" withExtension:@"wav"] error:nil];` Please mind the `withExtension` unlike `ofType` as you have used.

Answer (score 0):

It will work, You need to change your implementation like this. Please notice your `init` method.
`@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *cellTapSound;`

may be in `viewDidLoad`

```
cellTapSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ting" withExtension:@"wav"] error:nil];
[cellTapSound prepareToPlay];
```

Now may be on click of some button, you can give a shot like this :

```
 if (cellTapSound.isPlaying) [cellTapSound setCurrentTime:0.0];
[cellTapSound play];
```

hope that helps.